# Regexp htaccess not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website I want to save the MD5 of the user's IP in a cookie named "utm". How can I check, using htaccess, if the MD5 of the real user's IP %{REMOTE_ADDR} is exactly the one in the cookie? I want something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:MD5(%{REMOTE_ADDR}) ^.*utm=([^;]*).*:(?!\1).*$
```

I know it's not possible to use the MD5 in MD5(%{REMOTE_ADDR}) but how could I do this? The following code works fine but it does not use the MD5 to store the IP in the cookie and does not use the MD5 to check the cookie's IP:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}:%{REMOTE_ADDR} ^.*utm=([^;]*).*:(?!\1).*$
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you ought to be doing this with php rather than mod-rewrite.

Comment: You will need support of an external program like PHP to calculate md5. See this link: http://mykospark.net/2011/03/advanced-mod_rewrite-using-rewritemap/

Comment: thank you all! The link you provide me is great but I am in a shared hosting so it does not apply to me. If I cannot use MD5 inside htaccess is it possible to make any string manipulatino inside htaccess? Like, remove all dots from the IP and invert the numbers so it would not be so obvious to the user that the IP is being stored inside the cookie?

Comment: I think you may want to take a step back and reconsider your _general_ problem, because there may be a better approach to this than saving the MD5 of a user's IP address. If security is a concern at all, then that method's not sufficient to begin with.

Comment: Besides I don't think letting a use know his/her own IP is big security concern.

Comment: I have no problem about the user seeing the cookie because I use this htaccess only to prevent ddos attack on my pages that have a huge CPU usage. I demand that if the user wants to open those pages he/she must have a cookie setted. This was my first approach. After that I required that the cookie must be set but with the IP. And to make it even more ddos proof I want to save the cookie using the MD5 so I can check it back in the server. I already use Blockdos in my shared server but I want to add this extra layer which works perfectly except the MD5 which would make it amazing!

Comment: md5 shouldn't be used for anything security related. Using htaccess for logic is generally pointless. Just route all requests to a php file and let php take care of the logic and further routing.

Comment: @Samul if someone has the will and resource to DoS attack your server, then you'd have to have made a fortune from whatever your site does and can afford someone wiser than yourself to worry about the security. Even then, if someone wants to attack your server bad enough, they will probably succeed no matter what you do. Sony and Apple have been hacked... Also consider, you're adding more weight to your htaccess, which is a slow module already. You're DoS attacking yourself, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you all. With my htaccess I already prevented many ddos attack and saved 90% of what I used to pay to blockdos in the same periodo of last year. This one single line has saved more than 10 thousand dollar a month. It proves that is complete usefull.